# Deploying ASP.NET MVC 5 Application to IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2. when will browse its showing the root folders not routing to home page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have done the following

1. app pool configuration as .Net framework 4.0
2. Folder security (allow access for the app pool user)
3. Website security (anonymous access is needed for my site)
4. Re-register ASP.Net by running aspnet_regiis ad nauseam
5. Added the section in web config file as

   ```xml
   <system.webServer>
     <modules>
       <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
       <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>
     </modules>
   </system.webServer>
   ```

   I'd appreciate any pointers or personal experience.